# Admin url and themes not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I have installed Magento2 from git repository. Currently I'm not able to access admin URL and also theme is not applying.

I'm also referred http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html and in `/pub/static/` folder `frontend` and `adminhtml` directories are missing, only `_requirejs` folder exist.

Looks like I missed some commands to run. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: run in the command line `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and make sure that mod rewrite is enabled on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments....
You need to run  in the command line `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and make sure that mod rewrite is enabled on your server